# How Do I post JSON Data With Ajax Using C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, ajax, post

Hi all I am trying to post JSON to an API which I can do with AJAX and cURL.

The code in C# .net app can handle the cURL code and write it to SQL:

```
curl "http://localhost:38194/API/inbound" --data "FirstName=test4&LastName=test&Email=donot@mail.com"
```

However when I try to POST from C# with:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new 
    {
        FirstName = reader[1],
        LastName = reader[2],
        Email = reader[3]
    };

    var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:38194/API/inbound", 
        new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

It sends the data as `request = { FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Buckle", Email = "sdjsa@kjsdfhs.com" }` which I presume my Controller can't handle using:

```
public string Post([FromBody] FormDataCollection formValues)
```

I have searched and spent hours on this and suspect that the format that I sending the POST doesn't work with my API Controller `FormDataCollection`. I must admit I don't have a great understanding of this stuff and learn more by trial and error. Likely not elegant but this is my API Controller code that works with cURL.

```
public string Post([FromBody] FormDataCollection formValues)
{
    string first_name = null, last_name = null, email = null;

    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["inboundapplicant"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formValues.Get("FirstName")))
            {
                first_name = formValues.Get("FirstName");
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formValues.Get("LastName")))
            {
                last_name = formValues.Get("LastName");
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formValues.Get("Email")))
            {
                email = formValues.Get("Email");
            }

            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT into [dbo].[Leads] (FirstName, LastName, Email) VALUES (@first_name, @last_name, @email)";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", first_name == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : first_name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", last_name == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : last_name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : email);


            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    return "success";
}
```

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=Issue+Post+JSON+C%23+webapi should give you some answers...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing the json as request payload while you're trying to access it as FormData. No need to use [FromBody]

```
public string Post(FormDataCollection formValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a [FormBody] and don't use a FormDataCollection. You should create a model with the Firstname Lastname and Email as properties.

Your method then looks like this:

```
public string Post(PersonInformation personInformation)
```